# Where are contact form entries stored?

Tags: forms, 8, emails

I am aware that Webform is now out of the Window and has more or less been replaced by Core Contact Forms. I created a form and it works great. Only problem is, I can't for the life of me find out:

1. If it stores a copy of the submitted form locally?
2. Where it stores it if it does?
3. Or if it does not store it, how to allow it to be stored?

Like webforms, I want to click somewhere and see "Show all submissions". But no idea where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it really stores them anywhere by default, but I think that [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/contact_storage) wouldn't exist if it does store them. Check it out.